# Rails apartment gem config.excluded_models to include join_table users_roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, multi-tenant

My current setup is a multitenant app as per railscast
[389-multitenancy-with-postgresql](http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql)

I am attempting to move the setup to using the [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem mainly as it has good support to handle migrations across multiple schemas.

The issue I am having is that I use cancan and rolify gems resulting in my role model having this join table :users_roles

```
role.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
```

It is this join table that I would like to include in the apartment gem config for excluded models.  These models are designated to remain in the global(public) schema. This is my current setup

```
apartment.rb
config.excluded_models = ["User", "Tenant", "Role" ]
```

As per apartment site regarding excluded models:
*Note that a string representation of the model name is now the standard*

So how do I include the users_roles table in the excluded_models list when its not a model but simply a join table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Apartment, but can you switch from `habtm` to `has_many` and `belongs_to`?

In other words, you'd have:

```
# table 'users'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles 
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles

  # ...rest of class...
end

# table 'roles'
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles

  # ...rest of class....
end

# table 'user_roles'
class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role

  # ...rest of class...
end
```

And then in apartment.rb:

```
config.excluded_models = ["User", "Tenant", "Role", "UserRole" ]
```

Comment: This is a bit late but that is definitely one solution.  For my scenario it involved a few other gems with habtm so was pretty restricted that way.  


My solution in the past was to drop the apartment gem altogether and customize the entire multitenant process.  Great as a learning exercise.  I was then able to simply drop any tables from the tenants schema that were only in the public schema.  


I am just now hitting this same problem again so am revisiting the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The way I found to combine the rolify and apartment gems is to exclude the join model, as you have done, and to specify the join table name in rolify, including the `public` schema.

```
# apartment.rb

Apartment.configure do |config|
  config.excluded_models = %w{User Tenant Role UsersRole}

  # ...
end


# user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify role_join_table_name: 'public.users_roles'

  # ...
end
```

Comment: This was the solution for me as it appeared that Rolify wasn't including the "public" schema on the users_roles join table. Which I took the liberty of renaming to UserRole.

Thanks @troy!